# Swap fn key children keys function

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-layout, acer-aspire, fn-key

I just bought a new laptop, the Acer A715-72G and it has this very annoying feature. The F1-12 keys are swapped with the functions they also give. Like adjusting brightness and adjusting volume.

At the moment I have to kress `Fn + F1` to get the F1 functionality. I am a programmer and I use those keys for shortcuts all the time.

Can anyone tell me how I would swap the FN children keys with their functionality. So that pressing `F1` actually is `F1`. And not going into hybernation mode.

Also I need to only swap the F1-12 keys because my arrow keys are normal and their underlaying function with Fn is adjusting video speed. Which will also be very annoying if I have to press `Fn + Arrow_Left` if I want to scroll thru text while programming.

Is there anyone out their with the same problem and fixed this?

[image: Picture from keyboard I am talking about]

Comment: You may find that setting in UEFI.

Comment: If there is a way to do this, it's in the firmware settings for the system.  The exact name of the option to do this will vary by system, as will the exact way it works.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the BIOS setup environment and change the setting there. This is the place where the swap option is located in Acer machines.

If it is not there, please ensure that you have the latest version of BIOS installed.  If not, update it. In other forums I found that this update was a requirement before the option became available. It is possible that the option was missing in the earlier versions of the BIOS firmware.